# Quickest & most efficient way of formatting a String

Tags: java, string, string-matching

What is the quickest way for converting a date  which is a string with the format "20110913" to "2011-09-13" in Java.

Comment: But not sure about the perfomance,i wqould like to get better than this...

stringdate.substring(0,4)+'-'+stringdate.substring(4,6)+'-'+ stringdate.substring(6)

Comment: Maybe you should add a "string" tag to your question to indicate string-manipulation

Comment: You should mark your question as answered if you find satisfying answer.

Comment: "quick" is relative :-) without measuring and context, it's a pretty useless term. BTW, why is this tagged Swing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some simple profiling and found some interesting results.

```
public static String strcat(String ori){
    return ori.substring(0, 4) + '-' + ori.substring(4, 6) + '-' + ori.substring(6);
}

public static String sdf(String ori){
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date temp = in.parse(ori);
        return out.format(temp);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public static String sb(String ori){
    return new StringBuilder(10).append(ori.substring(0, 4)).append('-').append(ori.substring(4, 6)).append('-').append(ori.substring(6)).toString();
}

public static String nio(String ori){
    byte[] temp = ori.getBytes();
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(temp.length + 2);
    bb.put(temp, 0, 4);
    byte hyphen = '-';
    bb.put(hyphen);
    bb.put(temp, 4, 2);
    bb.put(hyphen);
    bb.put(temp, 6, 2);
    return new String(bb.array());
}

public static String qd(String ori){
    char[] result = new char[10];
    result[4] = result[7] = '-';

    char[] temp = ori.toCharArray();
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, result, 0, 4);
    System.arraycopy(temp, 4, result, 5, 2);
    System.arraycopy(temp, 6, result, 8, 2);
    return new String(result);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ori = "20110913";
    int rounds = 10000;
    for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
        qd(ori);
        nio(ori);
        sb(ori);
        sdf(ori);
        strcat(ori);
    }
}
```

With the above few methods, I ran the test three times and the results(averaged) are as follow:-

```
sb      15.7ms
strcat  15.2ms
qd      27.2ms
nio     137.6ms
sdf     582ms
```

The test is ran using JDK 7. Do take note that this is not an extensive profiling as there are a lot of optimization that can be done (e.g. caching the SimpleDateFormat, StringBuilder). Also, this test is not multithreaded. So, do profile your own program!
p.s. the strcat is faster than sb is not what I expected. I guess the compiler optimization plays a big role here.

Comment: strcat to sb: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Answer (score 5):

Use `java.text.DateFormat`:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
inputFormat.setLenient(false);
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse("20110913);
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(inputDate));
```

Comment: i used like this...  
stringdate.substring(0,4)+'-'+stringdate.substring(4,6)+'-'+ stringdate.substring(6)

Comment: As the title suggest, the author wants something fast. Using dateformat is slow. Using @K-ballo method is about 30x faster.

Comment: 30X faster of a small amount might still not be significant.  I doubt that the user's bottleneck has to do with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder, append the substrings inserting '-' chars in between them.